# Is there a way to allow automatic audio playback (alarm website)

Tags: javascript, audio, playback

I am creating a website that alerts when certain events happen with an audible alert. Since the arrival of chrome 66 it is not possible to play audio without the user making a gesture. For me this is a big problem, I was searching but I did not find any solid solution.

For example Youtube. When entering a link in the browser, the video starts automatically, without any user gesture. How do they do it?

It also occurred to me to ask for permission for the browser to allow automatic audio playback. Something like: "Notification.requestPermission ()". But I couldn't find how

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to a YouTube video link within YouTube itself, it doesn't actually navigate to a new page. YouTube uses a library called [Structured Page Fragments](http://youtube.github.io/spfjs/) (SPF) to render only relevant parts that need to be changed. Because of this, the browser doesn't consider this as a newly navigated page, and allows YouTube to automatically play videos with audio.

For example, from the Homepage, when you click a video in the Subscription box, this counts as a user interaction. The page then loads the fragments required to watch the video using SPF and - because the user is in the same navigation context as far as the browser is concerned - plays the video automatically with audio.

However, if you load the same video in a new navigation context (such as using a link from an external site, or opening it directly in a new tab) users will still need to interact with the page - in this case by clicking the video - to get audio. Once this is done, because the user has now interacted with the page and other videos are dynamically loaded using SPF, further interaction is not required for other videos to play automatically with audio in that navigation context.

Note that you don't need to specifically use SPF to achieve this effect. You can use libraries such as [Angular](https://angular.io) and [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) to change views with a click event, and these should still count as the user having interacted with the page.